# How to send KeyEvents through an input method service to a Dialog, or a Spinner menu?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method, key-events

I'm trying to implement an input method service that receives intents sent by a remote client, and in response to those sends an appropriate KeyEvent.

I'm using in the `input method service` this method

```
private void keyDownUp(int keyEventCode) 
{
    getCurrentInputConnection().sendKeyEvent(
              new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, keyEventCode));
    getCurrentInputConnection().sendKeyEvent(
              new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, keyEventCode));
}
```

to send `KeyEvents` as in the `Simple Sofykeyboard Sample`, and it works in the home, in `Activities.`.. but **it doesn't works when a Dialog or the menu of a Spinner is in foreground.**

The events is sent to the `parent activity behind the Dialog`.

Is there any way to send keys and control the device like using the hardware keys from an input method?

Better explanation on what I'm trying to do:

**I am kind of writng an Input Method that allows to control the device from remote.**

I write in a client (a java application on my desktop pc) a command (for example "UP"), a server on the device with `sendBroadcast()` sends the intent with the information, and a receiver in the input method gets it and call keyDownUp with the `keycode` of the `DPAD_UP key.`
It generally works, but when I go to an app that shows a dialog, the `keyDownUp` method don't sends the key event to the `dialog`, for example for select the yes or not buttons, but it keeps to control the `activty` behind the `Dialog`.

[**Here**](http://osdir.com/ml/Android-Developers/2009-09/msg03677.html)  I have found someone with my same problem... but no answer...

Answer (score 1):

First, let me explain what I did understand.

- You go to an app
- You open a Dialog in that activity (For example go to sms app, long press a thread)
- You press the HOME key.
- Go to a different application that sends the intent
- The IME gets the intent, and writes something down.

I don't understand how the activity with the Dialog gets opened again.

AFAIK, when you press a key in the softKeyboard, IME's `onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes)` is called and when you press a hard key the IME is called at:

- `public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)`
- `public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)`

You can try calling that methods instead, but I don't know if emulating a hard key would fix it. I guess it's a focus issue. Did you tried getting the text from `getCurrentInputConnection()` to see where it is standing?

Comment: I have edited my question trying to clarify what my problem is. In your example when I open the Dialog in the sms app, if i send the command DOWN for the DPAD_DOWN key, it doesn't make the dialog in the foreground to scroll, but it is sent to the activity behind, the one that shows the message list, selecting the message below the one I long pressed on, making impossible to close the dialog. I have tried to call onKeyDown and onKeyUp, but they don't work neither where the keyDownUp worked.

Comment: getCurrentInputConnection() always return a connection with activity that shows the dialog, and never the dialog. Using hard keys instead, you can scroll the dialog when it is focused, so i was wondering about how to emulate a hard key.

Comment: Hard key can surely be simulated with Instrumentation class, but requires rooted device.